# Заново загрузить удаленные папки из git

Tags: git, phpstorm

Время доброго.

Вся работа с git выполняется через IDE PhpStorm.

К проекту подключены два удаленных репозитория origin и base. В local/master были удалены несколько папок которые находились в base/master. Сделан commet и push в origin/master. Через некоторое время необходимо загрузить одну из папок из base/master. Выполняется через меню VCS > git > Pull, далее выбирается remote/base, отмечается галкой base/master, далее клик по кнопке Pull. Результат: Pull (no items). Как понимаю удаленные папки помечены удаленными и именно поэтому не загружаются.

Вопрос: Есть ли возможность загрузить удаленные папки (или только одну из них по выбору) использую интерфейс IDE, если да, то как? Если нет, то как это сделать через консоль?

Comment: Не знаю на счёт IDE, но вытащить папку из другого коммита можно тривиальным `git checkout <коммит/метка/ветка/и т. п.> <файл/папка>`.

Comment: @D-side Как всегда, все просто

Comment: Ответы — в ответы. Текст вопроса должен содержать только вопрос, а не решения.

Comment: @andreymal принял

Answer (score 0):

**Решение**: Перейти в ветку local/master. Открыть терминал (Alt+F12,View>Tool Windows>Terminal). Выполнить `git checkout base/master private/App/Components/Directory`. Путь к директории без папки проекта. Coomet, push.

**Сложное решение**: Создать новую локальную ветку от ветки base/master (VCS>git>Branches, base/maset>Checkout as new local...). Скопировать нужные папки за пределы папки проекта (Alt+Home,F5). Переключиться на ветку local/master. Перенести ранее скопированные папки в проект. Commet, push. Все выполняется из IDE.